# DJANGO : Problem of mixing between URL of web pages and media files

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls, django-static

I'm developing a website and sometimes I have a strange problem : the URL of the page is concatened with the URL of the images on this page, which means I cannot access to these images. It's a bit hard to explain so here is an example :

I have a view called "mes_plats" that displays some informations about meals cooked by a cooker. The informations are displayed with a background located at `static/media/img_background.jpg` and everything works correctly. I have another view called "supprimer_plat" (url : supprimer-plat) whose purpose is to delete the informations about a particular meal. This view render the same html template as the other one but this time the template try to access the following url for the background : `supprimer-plat/static/media/img_background.jpg`. Obviously the background isn't displayed. 
So my question is, why does the url of the page concatened to the URL of the image in one case and not in the other ? And how can I solve it ? Thanks in advance !

views.py

```
def mes_plats(request):
    return render(request, 'actualites/mes_plats.html', {'my_meals': Plat.objects.filter(chef=request.user.useradvanced.chef, date_prep__gte = date.today())})

def supprimer_plat(request, id):
    plat = get_object_or_404(Plat, id=id)
    plat.delete()
    return render(request, 'actualites/mes_plats.html', {'my_meals': Plat.objects.filter(chef=request.user.useradvanced.chef, date_prep__gte = date.today())})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('mes-plats', views.mes_plats, name = 'mes-plats'),
    path('supprimer-plat/<int:id>', views.supprimer_plat, name = 'supprimer-plat'),
]
```

mes_plats.html

```
<!doctype html>
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
   <body class="view" style="background-image: url('static/media/img_background.jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; background-position: center center;">
      SOME CODE
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: That is not strange: you do not start the url with a slash, so it is a *relative* path.

Comment: Yes that solves the problem thank you ! Can you explain me what was the matter when we don't start the url with a slash ? What is a relative path ?

Comment: I mean I guess a relative path is a path that is added after an URL, but why was it working for the first view ? Why doesn't it try to access ```mes-plats/static/media/img_background.jpg``` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is **expected** behavior. Your url is:

```
static/media/img_background.jpg
```

uses a *relative* path. So if the site is located at `foo.com/bar/qux`, then it will browse for `foo.com/bar/static/media/img_background.jpg`.

You thus can avoid that by prepending the path with a slash, like:

```
/static/media/img_background.jpg
```

But it might be better here to make use of Django's [`staticfiles` support [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/staticfiles/). After configuring this, you can use the [`{% static … %}` template tag [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-static) to "calculate" the urls.

Note that in deployment mode, you will need to configure your server to *serve* the static files itself. But you can still use the `{% static … %}` to calculate the URLs, and thus make it less likely to make mistakes.

Comment: Thank you ! I usually always use static but in this case, when I write ```background-image: {% static '/media/img_background.jpg' %};``` it is not working and I don't understand why. I used the inspector and there isn't an error, it's like it doesn't even try to access the image

Comment: @JulienMertz: you need to write `background-image: url({% static ... %})`.